# How to attach to an already running R script

Tags: r

I have an R script that has been running for a couple of days. I need to change something there but don't want to lose the calculations that have already been done. Is there a way to attach to it and pause and debug? Like with gdb you can attach to an already running process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that there is not. Not given that the script is already running.

Some extra info that won't make you feel better:

- You shouldn't write scripts that have to run for days (at least in R), at least not without having them write out RDS files to save your progress.
- You could've set up debugging in RStudio before you ran the script.
- If you were running Rcpp code you could've used `gdb` with it (more info from Hadley Wickam's site [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html)).
- You can learn more about debugging R code [here](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf).